# ng serve: Cannot find module 'tapable'

Tags: node.js, angular

I just transfered my Angular 5 project from one computer to another and in the new device I get the following error when trying to `ng serve`:

```
Cannot find module 'tapable'
Error: Cannot find module 'tapable'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\xampp\node_modules\webpack\lib\Template.js:7:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\xampp\node_modules\webpack\lib\node\NodeMainTemplatePlugin.js:5:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
```

I tried to:

1. Remove `node_modules` and run again `npm install`.
2. `npm install tapable`

My node version is 6.11.2 with npm 5.3.

Any idea what can solve it?

Comment: try `npm install tapable --save-dev`

Comment: @Faisal still same error, strange.. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix: I had to manually `npm install webpack` in order to solve this issue.