# ng serve : Cannot find module './templates.js'

Tags: node.js, angular, angular6

I just transfered my Angular 6 project from one computer to another and in the new device I get the following error when trying to `ng serve`

I have also tried with `npm install templates.js` , the dependency is installed but this error pops again

```
Cannot find module './templates.js'
Error: Cannot find module './templates.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:603:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:658:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Godwin\Desktop\livigro\node_modules\chalk\index.js:6:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:722:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:733:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:658:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Godwin\Desktop\livigro\node_modules\postcss\lib\css-syntax-error.js:9:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:722:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:733:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
```

This could be similar to [ng serve: Cannot find module 'tapable'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45843293/ng-serve-cannot-find-module-tapable)

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Did you import it at the beginning where you are consuming it?

Comment: no , can you tell how to import it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the `node_modules` folder and again using `npm install` solves the problem , and the `ng serve` working good

Answer (score 1):

**It can occur for two reasons:**

```
1. templates.js is not present.
2. templates.js is present but you provided the wrong relative path.
```

**Kindly check once. And you don't need to install "templates.js" if it's not an external package. Npm install is used for installing the external packages.**